# Shopify Latest sdk version

Tags: python, pagination, sdk, version, shopify

Shopify is upgrading api obviously something will have deprecated, one of them is pagination.

I am using python `sdk==5.1.2` but when I pass `page` filter it is working like

```
orders = shopify.Order.find(page=count)
```

but the real problem is that if it had deprecated how it is working.

Can someone clear this confusion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adam, 
I dont have much idea about python but have shopify. Yes shopify released [new cursor based pagination](https://developers.shopify.com/changelog/page-based-pagination-replaced-by-cursor-based-pagination-across-multiple-rest-endpoints). I review [shopify python sdk](https://github.com/Shopify/shopify_python_api/tree/master/shopify) . You can check whether you are using latest version or not.

You can check either **api_version.py** file exist in your shopify sdk then you can easily check version available in your api_version.py file.

To upgrade your use of ShopifyAPI you will need to make the following changes.

```
shopify.Session(domain, token)
```

is now

```
shopify.Session(domain, version, token)
```

For example if you want to use the 2019-04 version you would create a session like this:

```
session = shopify.Session(domain, '2019-04', token)
```

if you want to use the unstable version you would create a session like this:

```
session = shopify.Session(domain, 'unstable', token)
```